# Barplot in R Returning "Error in barplot.default(SurveyInfo, main = "State Anxiety Pre-Experiment",: 'height' must be a vector or a matrix"

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, error-messages-for

This is the line of code returning an error:

```
barplot(SurveyInfo, main="State Anxiety Pre-Experiment", xlab="ID", ylab="Anxiety Level", beside=TRUE, col=rainbow(7))
```

Note: I tried adding range of 1 into the code and it didn't fix the problem.

This is the previous code in the same script where I created the variable itself:

```
SubjInfo <- merge(SubjInfo,SubjInfoPre,by="ID") 
SurveyInfo <- SubjInfo %>% 
select(STAIY1_pre, STAIY1_post, STAIY2, BIS11, BDIII, RGPTSA, RGPTSB)
```

[This is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1v3p.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(SurveyInfo)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: the error is pretty self-explanatory, you need to turn `SurveyInfo` into a vector or matrix: `barplot(t(SurveyInfo))` or `barplot(t(t(SurveyInfo)))` which would be the same as `barplot(as.matrix(SurveyInfo))`